# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) in C valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

```
sentences = malloc(sizeof(int) * totalSentences);

for (int i = 0; i < totalSentences; i++) {
  sentences[i] = 0;
}

//Count characters in each sentence
int currentSentence = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  if (ispunct(*input_str)) {
    currentSentence++;
  }
  if (isalpha(*input_str)) {
    sentences[currentSentence]++;
  }
  input_str++;
}
```

For some reason on the line sentences[currentSentence]++ valgrind is giving me a 
    Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
error on that line. I thought that adding in a for loop after malloc that set all the values to 0 would solve this since now they have been initialized to a value, is there a different way that I should be doing that?

Comment: You can use `calloc()` to allocate zero-initialized memory instead of using a `for` loop with `malloc()`. You need to provide a [MCVE]. What is `input_str`, and how does it get a value?

Comment: From your snippets, the only thing that makes sense is that `length` is greater than `totalsentences` causing you to attempt access beyond your initialized values...

Comment: I am pretty sure you are misreading Valgrinds output (or compare it to the wrong source). "*Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)*" is expected with, well "jumps and moves", which the line you refer to does not do. Mostly likely Valgrind refers to one of the two if-statements where `*input_str` reads uninitialised memory.